# Can't #include in illustrator script code

Tags: javascript, json, include, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to read a [JSON file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RM016iV65zx7e8YRh7-X6u9SuVCQM68O/view?usp=sharing), in order to make changes in an illustrator document according to the data in that JSON file.

I tried this code:

```
#include 'libs/json2.js';
    
function readJSONFile(file) {

  file.open("r");
  var data = file.read();
  file.close();
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i in data) {
    $.writeln(i + "=" + data[i]);
  }
}
function getCorrections()
{
  const corrections = readJSONFile(File('C:/corrections.json'));
  alert(corrections);
}

getCorrections();
```

but when I run the script in Illustrator, it gives me an error saying *"JSON is undefined"*

so, I tried to use `#import` as I've seen in other Stackoverflow threads, but it seems like Illustrator don't accept that syntax.

```
#include 'libs/json2.js';
```

I get this error:

```
Error 23: ) does not not have a value.
Line: 1
-> ()
```

I would be glad to get some help importing an external library to my script, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// @include 'libs/json2.js'
```

But actually both of the variants work for me. `#includes` is a valid option for Illustrator.

Perhaps the problem is in your data. I could try to parse it if you provide the sample of your date.

Here is full code that works for me:

```
#include 'libs/json2.js';

var file = File('d:/stackoverflow/jsx/json/test.json'); // <-- a full path!!!
readJSONFile(file);

function readJSONFile(file) {
    file.open("r");
    var data = file.read();
    file.close();
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i in data) {
        $.writeln(i + "=" + data[i]);
    }
}
```

`test.json` file:

```
{
    "patches": [
        {
            "patchName": "N0",
            "offsetL": "1",
            "offsetA": "-1",
            "offsetB": "2"
        },
        {
            "patchName": "N1",
            "offsetL": "1",
            "offsetA": "-1",
            "offsetB": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything works fine:

[image]

Check the path to your json file.

You can get the folder that contains a current script this way:

```
var script_folder = File($.fileName).parent;

alert(script_folder); // 'd/stackoverflow/jsx/json' in my case
```

Comment: That's weird.. It gives me the same error, even though your code the line is a comment.

Comment: You can find an example JSON file I created for this task here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RM016iV65zx7e8YRh7-X6u9SuVCQM68O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you. See no problem in your data. Next step: are you sure that the `file` object you send into the function is correct? I'm getting a similar error if there is something wrong with a file.Try to read and to log the raw contents of the file and see what you have. For example there could be a relative path to the file (you need to use an absolute path).

Comment: Hmm..  I don't know, but it seems like the problem is with the first line. It gets stuck already there.

Comment: Just try to read the file and alert (of write to console) its contents

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do for a beginning. The rest of the code is 
`function getCorrections()
{
  const corrections = readJSONFile(File('corrections.json'));
  alert(corrections);
}

getCorrections();`

Comment: And the file `corrections.json` is in the same folder as the code file

Comment: `readJSONFile(File('corrections.json'))` it won't work. You need to use a full absolute path. Not a relative one.

Comment: Or you can use `readJSONFile(File(File($.fileName).parent + '/corrections.json'))` notation. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, full absolute path didn't work. The error is still in line 1.
Are you trying to run the code from within Illustrator? (Ctrl+F12 to open a script) Because I think Illustrator is having problems reading that syntax.

Comment: Just tried via Ctrl+F12. Everything works fine. But I'm using CS6. I'll try it in CC soon. Could you comment out the line `#include` and `JSON...` and just try to read your json file and print its contents in console?

Comment: I commented the first line and the `data = JSON...` line.
Now I get `undefined` error.

Comment: If you get `undefined` instead of contents of the file it means exactly that the script failed to read the file. Where the file is? How the path looks like? Can you put the file into another folder with short simply path like 'd:/temp' and try to read it with `var file = File('d/temp/my_file.json')`? Actually you can just take my snippet and replace my path with yours and see.

Comment: For the sake of troubleshooting, I moved the corrections file to C drive.
my code is `readJSONFile(File('c:/corrections.json')` but it still gives undefined error.

Comment: Add to your question your code and your json file exactly how they are now. (And as you can see your trouble has nothing to do with `#include`, it's a failed reading file operation, I'm sure)

Comment: I added the full code, thanks for the help

Comment: Please, add your json file to the question. Since it looks like the problem with the json file. And make sure by the way that the json file has a correct encoding (utf-8 without BOM)

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Here is the proof: https://imgur.com/34nfKY9.png And look, your function `readJSONFile(file)` has no `return` statement, so this: `const corrections = readJSONFile(...` will get you 'undefined' always

Comment: alright, thanks.
So I added `  return data;` at the end of the `readJSONFile` function, and now the alert works.

I have a different problem now, I removed the function `getCorrections()` and trying to get my json file useful, i.e. use the data in it.

`const corrections = readJSONFile(File('C:/corrections.json'));`

`var swatch = getSwatch(corrections.swatchName,placeholder)`

This code above returns an error that `var swatch is undefined`.

How do I access the value of `swatchName` correctly?

Comment: I also tried `alert(corrections.items[1]);` and get `Error 21: undefined is not an object`.

If I write `alert(corrections)` I get an alert message saying `[object: Object]`

Comment: (1) I don't see how the function `getSwatch()` looks like so it's hard to tell what's going on out there. (2) objects in your JSON have no property `swatchName`. For example if you need to get `patchName` property of the first object in the `corrections` object it can be done this way: `alert(corrections.patches[0].patchName);` it will return `N0`

Comment: Thank you very much, this has resolved my issue :)

Comment: THANK YOU! Been struggling with this for hours and your solution is the first that worked.